# nginx: infinite redirection from http to https and vice versa

Tags: nginx

I got a problem with infinite redirection on my site. Nginx redirects from http to https successfully but after that for some reason it does the opposite and that leads to infinite loop. What's wrong in my config?

````
erver {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name devcore.pw www.devcore.pw;

    return 301 https://devcore.pw$request_uri;
}

server {
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name www.devcore.pw devcore.pw; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on; 
    }

     #deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/devcore.pw/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/devcore.pw/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}```
````

Comment: I can see the redirection from `http` to `https`. Can you show the output of `curl -I` for the other one? Could your application be misconfigured and sending requests back to `http`?

Answer (score 0):

this config has major problem. you closed server block after the redirect line
so you have to fix it, try:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    server_name devcore.pw www.devcore.pw;
    return 301 https://devcore.pw$request_uri;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    root /var/www/html;
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on; 
    }

     #deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }


        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/devcore.pw/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/devcore.pw/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```